# Following the First Django App tutorial and I can't execute the runserver command

Tags: python, django

I can't get the django server to run.  I've been following this [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/) and I'm having no luck. Whenever I run the command `python manage.py runserver` I get the following:

```
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x1005d5950>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 72, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 96, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 21, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 127, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 97, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    __init__() keywords must be strings
```

Any input would be a big help. I'm working on Mac 10.6 and using Python 2.6.1
I've tried reinstalling django and python.

EDIT:  Here's the code to my models.py file.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text, force_text
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

class ContentTypeManager(models.Manager):

# Cache to avoid re-looking up ContentType objects all over the place.
# This cache is shared by all the get_for_* methods.
_cache = {}

def get_by_natural_key(self, app_label, model):
    try:
        ct = self.__class__._cache[self.db][(app_label, model)]
    except KeyError:
        ct = self.get(app_label=app_label, model=model)
        self._add_to_cache(self.db, ct)
    return ct

def _get_opts(self, model, for_concrete_model):
    if for_concrete_model:
        model = model._meta.concrete_model
    elif model._deferred:
        model = model._meta.proxy_for_model
    return model._meta

def _get_from_cache(self, opts):
    key = (opts.app_label, opts.object_name.lower())
    return self.__class__._cache[self.db][key]

def get_for_model(self, model, for_concrete_model=True):
    """
    Returns the ContentType object for a given model, creating the
    ContentType if necessary. Lookups are cached so that subsequent lookups
    for the same model don't hit the database.
    """
    opts = self._get_opts(model, for_concrete_model)
    try:
        ct = self._get_from_cache(opts)
    except KeyError:
        # Load or create the ContentType entry. The smart_text() is
        # needed around opts.verbose_name_raw because name_raw might be a
        # django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object.
        ct, created = self.get_or_create(
            app_label = opts.app_label,
            model = opts.object_name.lower(),
            defaults = {'name': smart_text(opts.verbose_name_raw)},
        )
        self._add_to_cache(self.db, ct)

    return ct

def get_for_models(self, *models, **kwargs):
    """
    Given *models, returns a dictionary mapping {model: content_type}.
    """
    for_concrete_models = kwargs.pop('for_concrete_models', True)
    # Final results
    results = {}
    # models that aren't already in the cache
    needed_app_labels = set()
    needed_models = set()
    needed_opts = set()
    for model in models:
        opts = self._get_opts(model, for_concrete_models)
        try:
            ct = self._get_from_cache(opts)
        except KeyError:
            needed_app_labels.add(opts.app_label)
            needed_models.add(opts.object_name.lower())
            needed_opts.add(opts)
        else:
            results[model] = ct
    if needed_opts:
        cts = self.filter(
            app_label__in=needed_app_labels,
            model__in=needed_models
        )
        for ct in cts:
            model = ct.model_class()
            if model._meta in needed_opts:
                results[model] = ct
                needed_opts.remove(model._meta)
            self._add_to_cache(self.db, ct)
    for opts in needed_opts:
        # These weren't in the cache, or the DB, create them.
        ct = self.create(
            app_label=opts.app_label,
            model=opts.object_name.lower(),
            name=smart_text(opts.verbose_name_raw),
        )
        self._add_to_cache(self.db, ct)
        results[ct.model_class()] = ct
    return results

def get_for_id(self, id):
    """
    Lookup a ContentType by ID. Uses the same shared cache as get_for_model
    (though ContentTypes are obviously not created on-the-fly by get_by_id).
    """
    try:
        ct = self.__class__._cache[self.db][id]
    except KeyError:
        # This could raise a DoesNotExist; that's correct behavior and will
        # make sure that only correct ctypes get stored in the cache dict.
        ct = self.get(pk=id)
        self._add_to_cache(self.db, ct)
    return ct

def clear_cache(self):
    """
    Clear out the content-type cache. This needs to happen during database
    flushes to prevent caching of "stale" content type IDs (see
    django.contrib.contenttypes.management.update_contenttypes for where
    this gets called).
    """
    self.__class__._cache.clear()

def _add_to_cache(self, using, ct):
    """Insert a ContentType into the cache."""
    model = ct.model_class()
    key = (model._meta.app_label, model._meta.object_name.lower())
    self.__class__._cache.setdefault(using, {})[key] = ct
    self.__class__._cache.setdefault(using, {})[ct.id] = ct

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ContentType(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
model = models.CharField(_('python model class name'), max_length=100)
objects = ContentTypeManager()

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('content type')
    verbose_name_plural = _('content types')
    db_table = 'django_content_type'
    ordering = ('name',)
    unique_together = (('app_label', 'model'),)

def __str__(self):
    # self.name is deprecated in favor of using model's verbose_name, which
    # can be translated. Formal deprecation is delayed until we have DB
    # migration to be able to remove the field from the database along with
    # the attribute.
    #
    # We return self.name only when users have changed its value from the
    # initial verbose_name_raw and might rely on it.
    model = self.model_class()
    if not model or self.name != model._meta.verbose_name_raw:
        return self.name
    else:
        return force_text(model._meta.verbose_name)

def model_class(self):
    "Returns the Python model class for this type of content."
    from django.db import models
    return models.get_model(self.app_label, self.model,
                            only_installed=False)

def get_object_for_this_type(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Returns an object of this type for the keyword arguments given.
    Basically, this is a proxy around this object_type's get_object() model
    method. The ObjectNotExist exception, if thrown, will not be caught,
    so code that calls this method should catch it.
    """
    return self.model_class()._base_manager.using(self._state.db).get(**kwargs)

def get_all_objects_for_this_type(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Returns all objects of this type for the keyword arguments given.
    """
    return self.model_class()._base_manager.using(self._state.db).filter(**kwargs)

def natural_key(self):
    return (self.app_label, self.model)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your models are invalid. It will be easy to help if you can share code inside your `models.py`.

In the meantime please have a look at [Django: Error when calling the metaclass bases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657532/django-error-when-calling-the-metaclass-bases), a related question.